# Laravel ErrorException (E_WARNING) fopen Upload does not work - ONLY FOR SOME FILES on S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, filesystems, fopen

I just started (it wasn't happening before, upload was working fine) getting this error with my file uploads; I am currently on local development environment..

```php
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
fopen(C:\Users\******\****\***): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

My upload script;

```php
$filepath = $attachment->storeAs("pdocs/customers", $formattedname);
```

The weird thing is that it only happens with some files. I am able to upload for instance some image files I have on my desktop.  I am uploading it to my s3 account.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happen because you don't have permission to create the file in `storage` folder, you can try to test in your develop directory:

```sh
chmod -R 777 /storage
```

**IMPORTANT**: don't enable 777 in **production server**. You can read about [how to enable storage here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/11639058)

Comment: I dont understand.... I am trying to upload to my s3 disk.(not local disk) I am not doing anything on local. Second thing, How come I get this error with some of the files I tried to upload?

Comment: @eleven0 I think this a duplicate post, [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724235/11639058)

Answer (score 0):

After couple of tries, I noticed that I only had this issue with files bigger than 2MB. So change your local php.ini file;

```
post_max_size = 124M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

After doing this, problem was solved.